# it of them in the sentence

Tags: pronouns

> I had to saw off the lower limbs of the tree to keep my young kids
> from climbing it.

or

> I had to saw off the lower limbs of the tree to keep my young kids
> from climbing them.

Does the pronoun relate with the tree or limbs?

Comment: It's the one you wish to use that decides the meaning of the sentence— both are correct sentences and mean different things.

Comment: The pronoun should relate to the tree, as we don't really "climb limbs."

Comment: The reason you sawed off the lower limbs was to prevent your children from using them--climbing them-- to get to the higher limbs! Obviously, you were concerned for their safety.